# python for loop with if statement not returning items

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to learn python through some basic exercises with my own online store. I have a list of parts that are in-transit to us that we have already ordered, and I have a list of parts that we are currently out of stock of. I want to be able to send a list to the supplier of what we need - but I do not want to create duplicate orders as a result of the fact that the parts on order, are listed as out of stock.

I put together this basic program that looks through the list of items that are out of stock and only prints the item if it is present in the outofstock list but *not* present in the onorder list, so that if it is on order we do not order it again. However, it outputs nothing.

```
onorder = ["A1417", "A1322", "ISL6259", "LP8545B1SQ", "PM6640", "SLG3NB148V", "PD4HDMIREG", "338S1201", "SN2400B0", "AD7149", "J3801", "J4502", "IPRO97B"]
outofstock = ["ISL6259", "LY-UVH900", "triwing", "banana-to-alligator", "LP8548B1SQ", "EDP-J9000-30-PIN-IPEX", "J3801", "LT3470", "PM6640", "SN2400B0", "IPRO97B", "SLG3NB148V", "SN2400AB0", "usbammeter", "821-00814-A", "J5713", "343S0645", "PMCM4401VPE", "J4502", "PMD9645", "J9600", "J2401", "AD7149", "593-1604", "821-1722", "LM3534TMX", "U4001"]

for part in onorder:
    if (part in onorder) == False and (part in outofstock) == True:
    print (part)
```

It doesn't print anything, even though there are entries in outofstock that are not in onorder.

If I try this outside of a loop, it works and prints every part in the onorder list.

```
for part in onorder:
    print (part)
```

If I try this outside a loop, it also works and prints triwing, since it is true that triwing is in the outofstock list.

```
if ('triwing' in outofstock) == True:
    print ("triwing")
```

However, the program in the for loop returns nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: Why not `if part not in order and part in outofstock:`?

Comment: Indent `print (part)` by four spaces.

Comment: `for part in onorder` guarantees that `part in onorder` is always true.

Comment: I tried `if (part not in onorder) and (part in outofstock):`, same result. is `print (part)` not indented in the above example? I will check out what you had to say on duplicate of in operator. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yep, there's two issues. `if part not in onorder and part in outofstock:` would be the correct approach, if you weren't actually iterating through `onorder` in the first place meaning that the first condition can _never_ be True.

Answer (score 3):

```
for part in onorder:
    if (part in onorder) == False ...
```

This does not make sense. Since you are iterating over exactly every element of `onorder`, you will never get a `part` not in `onorder`. Therefore, it is not a miracle that the print statement is not being executed.

Answer (score 2):

You're looping over the wrong list. To find items in `outofstock` but not in `onorder`, loop over `outofstock`:

```
for part in outofstock:
    if part not in onorder:
        print(part)
```

Simpler would be to convert both lists to sets, and compute the difference:

```
print(set(outofstock) - set(onorder))
```

Answer (score 0):

Doh! Appropriate code was

```
for part in outofstock:
if (part not in onorder):
    print (part)
```

This way it prints my out of stock items which I need to order, unless they were already on order.

I can't believe I overly complicated this for no good reason. Thank you so much for pointing out where I had gone wrong. This was such a dumb question in hindsight.